# Coworkers acting like I have coronavirus

Tags: colleagues, health

I am a resident of Omaha, Nebraska.  I have never traveled internationally, and have only thrice in my life even traveled outside of Nebraska.  I am fairly introverted, and usually spend my free time by myself.

With the corona virus scare, some of my coworkers have started wearing surgical masks to work.  I realized the other day that they only put it on when I'm in the room, and take it off when I leave.  They denied it when I asked them about it.

Asking another coworker (who doesn't wear a surgical mask) about it, she said she heard from somebody else that there's a fear of me having the corona virus because I'm always eating Chinese food.  I was really puzzled, especially considering I hate Chinese food.  It turns out they were referring to the time I bought in a bowl of white rice, which they thought was from China for some reason.  (I checked, and the box says it came from Arkansas).

I confronted them again on the next day, but they denied it saying they're not targeting me specifically, but just being cautious by wearing the mask.  But then they went back to putting on the mask only when I was in the room, and taking it off and soon as I started walking away.

I was going to call my boss and complain about it.  (He works out the North Dakota branch).  But then my boss sent out an e-mail saying he was going to self quarantine for 14 days because somebody in Minnesota was diagnosed, and now he's afraid he's going to get it.

I find this whole thing a bit silly and annoying.  Is there anything I can do about this?  Should I contact HR for harassment or something?  Or should I just try to ignore my coworkers and go back to happily eating my boxed white rice from Arkansas?

Comment: *"I find this whole thing a bit silly and annoying"* - I am sure it does. This seems like a highly illogical response from part of your coworkers

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Because this whole question premise is silly. I wonder if it's even looking to get a serious answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I find this whole thing a bit silly and annoying.

It is silly, and uninformed, and ignorant.

> Is there anything I can do about this?

Why? What would you do?

> Should I contact HR for harassment or something?

Is this behavior really harassment? Can you prove that you're intentionally being targeted? What kind of harassment is this, exactly?

> Or should I just try to ignore my coworkers and go back to happily
>   eating my boxed white rice from Arkansas?

Yes. Do that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they're using this opportunity to make fun of you.

> Should I contact HR for harassment or something?

If they lied to you, they will lie to HR.

> Or should I just try to ignore my coworkers and go back to happily
>   eating my boxed white rice from Arkansas?

Yes, ignore your coworkers.

But don't defend yourself by saying that the box is from Arkansas. That would be counterproductive.

Comment: Only 2% of US rice imports are coming from China. And coronavirus doesn't spread through rice. Especially not since rice is cooked at hot temperature which kills the virus. Try convincing your co-workers to hold their breath while you are nearby. At least that will make them shut up. Wearing a mask is of no use whatsoever. Are they washing their hands regularly?

Comment: Yes I agree with this approach. Realistically the mask prevents the wearing from spreading the virus. Reality is the virus transfer mostly by surface contact then rubbing your eyes or nose or putting your hands in your mouth.